# Integral defining expectation of $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: integration, statistics

If U has a $\chi^2$ distribution with v df, find E(U) and V(U).

By definition, $E(U)
=\int^{\infty}_{0} u\frac{1}{\gamma(\frac{v}{2})2^\frac{v}{2}}u^{\frac{v}{2}-1} e^\frac{-u}{2}\,du 
=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{\gamma(\frac{v}{2})2^\frac{v}{2}}u^\frac{v}{2} e^\frac{-u}{2}\,du$.

How do I integrate this?

NOTE: I already know that this question has been asked originally however there were not steps on how to integrate it. Just a short hand solution. I would like someone to show me not only the steps but also what the do with the Gamma function as well.

Thanks!

Comment: how is my solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651018/help-with-an-integral-for-if-u-has-a-chi2-distribution-with-v-df-find-eu/651048?noredirect=1#comment1742948_651048 in anyway, a short hand? I literally explained every single step used... In fact, it is almost identical to the answer below.

Comment: Whoah, chill out.

Answer (score 1):

You know that, for every positive $v$,
$$
I(v)=\int^{\infty}_{0}u^{(v/2)-1}\mathrm e^{-u/2}\,\mathrm du =\Gamma(v/2)\,2^{v/2},
$$
and you are looking for the value of
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}u\cdot u^{(v/2)-1}\mathrm e^{-u/2}\,\mathrm du=\int^{\infty}_{0}u^{v/2}\mathrm e^{-u/2}\,\mathrm du.
$$
Sure no idea pops up?

Comment: I actually went back to my mathematical statistics book and remembered it. I'll keep working.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. My answer is supposed to suggest an approach...

Comment: I just went through your approach twice now and must be making some sort of error that I'm not catching. However yes I do understand your approach and it has helped.

Comment: Additional hint: the second integral in my post is $I(w)$ for some specific $w$.